# No 'id' member found on type 'app4.MainActivity' Connecting Xamarin.Android To Azure

Tags: android, visual-studio, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

I just tried to Inserting a data to azure platform. But that problem occurred.
No 'id' member found on type 'app4.MainActivity' I used a break points for examination the problem and it goes to the catch line at " JObject jo = new JObject(); or the next line (now break points doesnt work) "

```
 using Android.App;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.OS;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
    using Android.Views;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;

    namespace App4
    {
    [Activity(Label = "App4", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        public TextView txtShow;
        public EditText txtEnter;
        public Button btnSave;



       // string id;
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return Id; }
            set { Id = value; }
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Questions")]
        public string Questions { get; set; }

       /* [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "complete")]
        public bool Complete { get; set; }*/


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button btnSave = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSave);


            TextView txtShow = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtSoru);
            EditText txtEnter = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtSoruGir);

            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
            SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();

            // IMobileServiceTable<MainActivity> SurveyTable = client.GetTable<MainActivity>();




            // Initialization for Azure Mobile Apps
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
            // This MobileServiceClient has been configured to communicate with the Azure Mobile App and
            // Azure Gateway using the application url. You're all set to start working with your Mobile App!
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient TrendDemoClient = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient(
            "http://xxxx.azurewebsites.net");

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        }

        // It is save button. ( or insert button)using on xml 
       // using via   android:onClick="AddItem"
        [Java.Interop.Export()]
        public async void AddItem(View view)
        {
            var client = new MobileServiceClient("http://*****.azurewebsites.net/");
            IMobileServiceTable SurveyTable = client.GetTable("Survey");
            var table = client.GetSyncTable<MainActivity>();
            txtEnter.Text = txtShow.Text;
            string txt;
            txt = txtShow.Text;

            var item = new MainActivity
            {
                Questions = txtShow.Text,


            };

                  Questions = txt;

            try
            {

////the problem occur over here and goes to catch
                JObject jo = new JObject();
                jo.Add("id", "myemail@emaildomain.com");
                jo.Add("Questions", "Hello World");
               // jo.Add("Complete", false);
            ////  It does't come so far
                var inserted = await table.InsertAsync(jo);


                // var inserted = await table.InsertAsync(Questions);



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Amk Necosu");
            }



        }

        private void CreateAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title)
        {
            CreateAndShowDialog(exception.Message, title);
        }

        private void CreateAndShowDialog(string message, string title)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.SetMessage(message);
            builder.SetTitle(title);
            builder.Create().Show();
        }
    }
    }
```

**Backend Part is here**
[image: Backend Part is here]

**Controller.cs**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.OData;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;
using TrendDemoService.DataObjects;
using TrendDemoService.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Config;

namespace TrendDemoService.Controllers
{
    [MobileAppController]
    public class Controller : TableController<MyFirstDbTableModel>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            Context context = new Context();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<MyFirstDbTableModel>(context, Request);
        }

        // GET tables/TodoItem
        public IQueryable<MyFirstDbTableModel> GetAllMyFirstDbTableModels()
        {
            return Query();
        }

        // GET tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public SingleResult<MyFirstDbTableModel> GetMyFirstDbTableModel(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }

        // PATCH tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task<MyFirstDbTableModel> PatchMyFirstDbTableModel(string id, Delta<MyFirstDbTableModel> patch)
        {
            return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }

        // POST tables/TodoItem
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMyFirstDbTableModel(MyFirstDbTableModel item)
        {
            MyFirstDbTableModel current = await InsertAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }

        // DELETE tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task DeleteTodoItem(string id)
        {
            return DeleteAsync(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Context.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables;
using TrendDemoService.DataObjects;

namespace TrendDemoService.Models
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to alter your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        // For more information refer to the documentation:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

        public Context() : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<MyFirstDbTableModel> MyFirstDbTableModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
                new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                    "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
        }
    }

}
```

**MyFirstDbTableModel**
    using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;

```
namespace TrendDemoService.DataObjects
{
    public class MyFirstDbTableModel : EntityData
    {

        public string Questions { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

### **AFTER EDIT**

**Startup.MobileApp**

```
Backend Part
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Config;
using TrendDemoService.DataObjects;
using TrendDemoService.Models;
using Owin;

namespace TrendDemoService
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);

            // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
            Database.SetInitializer(new TrendDemoInitializer());

            // To prevent Entity Framework from modifying your database schema, use a null database initializer
            // Database.SetInitializer<TrendDemoContext>(null);

            MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
            {
                // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
                // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
                app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                    ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                    TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
                });
            }
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }

    public class TrendDemoInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>
    {
        protected override void Seed(Context context)
        {
            List<MyFirstDbTableModel> todoItems = new List<MyFirstDbTableModel>
            {
                new MyFirstDbTableModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Questions = "First item", Complete = false },
                new MyFirstDbTableModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Questions = "Second item", Complete = false },
            };

            foreach (MyFirstDbTableModel todoItem in todoItems)
            {
                context.Set<MyFirstDbTableModel>().Add(todoItem);
            }

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

**Frontend**

**MainActivity**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Android.Views;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;



namespace App4
{
    [Activity(Label = "App4", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]

    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        public TextView txtShow;
        public EditText txtEnter;
        public Button btnSave;










        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button btnSave = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSave);


            TextView txtShow = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtSoru);
            EditText txtEnter = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtSoruGir);

            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
            SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();

            // IMobileServiceTable<MainActivity> SurveyTable = client.GetTable<MainActivity>();




            // Initialization for Azure Mobile Apps
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
            // This MobileServiceClient has been configured to communicate with the Azure Mobile App and
            // Azure Gateway using the application url. You're all set to start working with your Mobile App!
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient TrendDemoClient = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient(
            "http://******.azurewebsites.net");

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        }


);




        [Java.Interop.Export()]
        public async void AddItem(View view)
        {
              var client = new MobileServiceClient("http://xx.azurewebsites.net/");
            // IMobileServiceTable SurveyTable = client.GetTable("Survey");
            var table = client.GetSyncTable<MyFirstDbTableModel>();





            var myFirstModelInstance = new MyFirstDbTableModel();

            myFirstModelInstance.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            myFirstModelInstance.Questions = "Could I help you with this answer?";
            myFirstModelInstance.Complete = false;



            try
            {






                await table.InsertAsync(myFirstModelInstance);

            }




            catch (Exception e)
            {
              CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");

            }



        }

        private void CreateAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title)
        {
            CreateAndShowDialog(exception.Message, title);
        }

        private void CreateAndShowDialog(string message, string title)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.SetMessage(message);
            builder.SetTitle(title);
            builder.Create().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFirstDbTableModel Class**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace App4
{
    public class MyFirstDbTableModel
    {
        // string id;
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Questions { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }
    }

}
```

[image]

### The Error Message has changed.

**Error
*-Synccontext is not yet initialized***

---

**Output (when I press the Button )**

```
06-28 14:20:48.971 D/ViewRootImpl@16dc384[MainActivity]( 4390): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
06-28 14:20:49.025 D/ViewRootImpl@16dc384[MainActivity]( 4390): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
06-28 14:20:49.075 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
06-28 14:20:49.079 D/InputTransport( 4390): Input channel constructed: fd=74
06-28 14:20:49.079 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): setView = DecorView@279674[MainActivity] touchMode=true
06-28 14:20:49.081 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): dispatchAttachedToWindow
06-28 14:20:49.093 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[36,1062][1404,1593] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 504091385344} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
06-28 14:20:49.094 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 504091385344} hwInitialized=true
06-28 14:20:49.099 D/mali_winsys( 4390): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1624x787]-format:1
06-28 14:20:49.099 D/ScrollView( 4390):  onsize change changed 
06-28 14:20:49.110 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
06-28 14:20:49.110 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 504091385344}
06-28 14:20:49.124 D/ViewRootImpl@5067e47[MainActivity]( 4390): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
06-28 14:20:49.141 D/ViewRootImpl@16dc384[MainActivity]( 4390): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
06-28 14:20:49.142 D/SEM_CLIP_SemClipboardManager( 4390): isCocktailBarDisplayed : false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use your MainActivity as database model. You shouldn't do that.

What you should do:

1. Create a database table model:

   ```
   public class MyFirstDbTableModel
   {
      // string id;
      public string Id { get; set; }

      public string Questions { get; set; }

      public bool Complete { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Get the table like this:

   ```
   var table = client.GetTable<MyFirstDbTableModel>();
   ```
3. Create an instance of your database table model and add values:

   ```
   var myFirstModelInstance = new MyFirstDbTableModel();
   myFirstModelInstance.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   myFirstModelInstance.Questions = "Could I help you with this answer?";
   myFirstModelInstance.Complete = false;
   ```
4. Put the instance to the database in Azure:

   ```
   var inserted = await table.InsertAsync(myFirstModelInstance);
   ```

---

Notice: It is necessary, that you have created the database table from the backend or directly in the database. You can use the "MyFirstDbTableModel" model directly in the backend, but it must inherit from

> public class MyFirstDbTableModel : EntityData {...}

and you have to do some more stuff, like to create a controller, which is described in the Azure documentation or you can see it in the Azure Mobile Apps Quickstart example.

---

**Update based on the edit of the question:**

You should change the class name from "Controller" to "MyFirstDbTableModelController". The name of the controller is reflected in the request link.

You should connect to your database with SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). With this program you can see, whether the table is already created. Note: The table will only created, after you has send a request to the backend.

You don't use attributes in your model, with this, I have removed the attributes in step 3.

Have you changed the Initializer in the Startup.MobileApp.cs?

If you use the code in my answer, it should work with the changes from my update.

If you getting an exception, please post the stacktrace. Additionally you can debug the backend, as well, to get an stacktrace.

Notice: If you change the model, for example the MyFirstDbTableModel, the database will not create the table again. You have to drop all tables in the db.

Comment: Thanks sir, I realized huge mistake.  I didn't do anything in the backend. I thought azure do everything automaticaly. I will try to create a backend (controller etc.) tomorrow. By the way can you edit your answer.   **Guid()**.NewGuid().ToString(); instead of **Guid**.NewGuid().ToString(); and var myFirstModelInstance = new My**Frist**DbTableModel();

Comment: I recommend you to use the TodoItem Quickstart example, to see how the backend works and how the mobile application works. If you create a Mobile Apps instance in Azure, you can click on "Quickstart", then you can choose your target, like Xamarin.iOS. After that you have to create a SQL database and so on.. (It's a step by step procedure, you will see) P.S.: I have corrected the mistakes, thank you.

Comment: I have edited my backend code and publish but its still have same error.

Comment: @martlost I have updated my answer. Can you update your code from the MainActivity?

Comment: Step 4 : **var inserted = await table.InsertAsync(myFirstModelInstance);** There is a error here "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable App4"
So, I still use  **"await table.InsertAsync(myFirstModelInstance);"**

I changed the "**Controller**" to "**MyFirstDbTableModelController**" and publish again.

I Connected to DB I can see the Table which ı was created before via Easy Tables. Name is **"MyFirstDbTableModel"**

I added to question the **"startup.mobileapp.cs"**

Comment: By the way the error message has changed. I searching it now

Comment: Ahhh I have made a mistake, look at step 2. I have updated my answer. You can't not use .GetSyncTable. For offline sync, you have to do a little bit more.

Comment: Interesting point is a new table created and name is the table is MyFirstDbTableModel**s** why ? Which code  causes this situation ?

Comment: If you start the Mobile App at the first time and if you make your first request, then the "Startup.MobileApp.cs" will be called once and with it the Entity Framework creates the tables in the database. The Framework adds the "s" at the end of the tablename, based on the "Context.cs" in the line "DBSet ...". I think the Entity Framework adds the "s" because you use the name of the model for creating the table and in this table are many items of your model. So the Framework add the "s" to make it to a plural name. I'm not sure with that, but it sounds logical for me.

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }
```

You are returning Id which in turns return Id, so it is a recursive call. It can't work.

I also agree with Sean that this isn't the best practice to add the data to Azure.